# Laravel 4 localization in library

Tags: php, localization, laravel

I'm translating an application written in Laravel 4.
When I tried to translate a line in a library file, I got an error, and after some time, I figured you can't set the translation directly to a variable in a library file.
The following lines

```
class Service {

    private $test = trans('general.name');
```

produces the following

> syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

pointing at the "private $test" line.

I'd like to add that I can normally translate and set to a variable if it's in a function, or in a different kind of file, i.e. a view.

Does anyone have an answer to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a function in a class variable. You should do something like:

```
<?php

class Service {

    private $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = trans('general.name');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But am I wrong to think your suggestion won't work on static variables? Could something be done in that case?

Comment: @user2423399 if you're using L4 probably you should use the class variables for language strings. You can provide your packages with translations if you want, it will be easier I think!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Service {

private $name;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->name = trans('general.name');
}

public static function test() {
    $service = new Service;
    return $service->name;
}
```

}

Here your static solution:

```
echo Service::test();
```

It is not perfect solution but can be useful in some cases